# convert unsigned short mat to vector in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

I load a depth image in opencv with

```
cv::Mat depth = cv::imread("blabla.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

then get a subimage of it with

```
cv::Mat sub_image= depth(cv::Rect( roi_x,roi_y,roi_size,roi_size)).clone();
```

now I want to convert that sub_image into a vector

I try with

```
std::vector<uchar> array;
array.assign(sub_image.datastart,sub_image.dataend);
```

that found here in StackOverflow in a similar question but it seems it doesnt work properly.

The size of array after assignment isnt roi_size * roi_size,
but instead roi_size*roi_size*2

Is something wrong with the type of vector?? I also tried various other types like double, float, int, etc

The type of the depth image is unsigned short right??

Edit:

array fills properly (correct size roi_size*roi_size) when I normalize the depth image

```
cv::Mat depthView;
cv::normalize(depth, depthView, 0, 255, cv::NORM_MINMAX,CV_8UC1);
```

but thats not what I want to do

Comment: already tried, didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys,
I think I managed to solve the problem.

I changed the code for the array assignment to this

```
std::vector<unsigned short> array(sub_image.begin<unsigned short>(),sub_image.end<unsigned short>());
```

and now the size is correct roi_size*roi_size

thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation of `roi_size*roi_size*2` was due to the fact that the depth image is of `short` type which is each of size `2 bytes`. You are trying to push this image data to an array of type `unsigned char`.

Make the vector type to `short` and you will find that the array size got back to `roi_size*roi_size` as expected. The values too would be what you expected it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking, which type of image you read, i.e. with `depth.type() == CV_8UC1` for 8-bit uchar with 1 channel.

Maybe your image was interpreted defferently.
Have you tried reading the image with the flag `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE` instead of `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED`?

Comment: std::cout<<depth.type() returns 2 which according to this

http://ninghang.blogspot.gr/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html

my depth image is CV_16U with 1 channel,
loading it with CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE makes its type 0 and meshes with its values

Comment: The official enum can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/intro.html#fixed-pixel-types-limited-use-of-templates)

Comment: so according to that it would be ushort?

Comment: yeah thats true,
but make the array ushort
std::vector<ushort> array;
doesnt help either for whatever the reason...

Comment: Since `sizeof(unsinged char) = 1` and `sizeof(unsinged short) = 2`, I would also suggest trying `std::vector<unsinged short>`, as @GPPK wrote. Alternatively you would have ot convert the cv::Mat or the image , if you need it to be `unsigned char`.

Comment: std::vector<unsigned short> array; doesnt correct the size of the array,
I dont know what I am doing wrong
but type of array seems it doesnt affect its size
type of depth on the other hand does, and I dont want to convert it to unsigned char...

Comment: What is the output of `depth.channels()`? If I understand that correct, a depth map should only have one channel, so the output should be 1. If the output is 2, than cv::Mat might also stores the alpha value.

Comment: depth.channels() returns 1